# I found "Error: `path` must be a string" when i tried to run subscript of a loop in R using readxl package. Help would be appreciated

Tags: r, string, readxl

I have tried to run the script of loop that opens every one of the files and adds them to the blank data frame.

```
fileNames <- list.files(pattern=".xlsm", recursive = TRUE)
fileNumbers <- seq(fileNames)

excel.data <- read_excel(fileNames[fileNumber], 
                      skip=1, 
                      col_names = T,
                      sheet = "Output")`
```

It is a part of loop:

```
for (fileNumber in fileNumbers){  
  tryCatch({
    # read in the data from excel. 
    excel.data <- read_excel(fileNames[fileNumber], 
                      skip=1, 
                      col_names = T,
                      sheet = "Output")........}).
```

Loops run correct but gives blank column for the excel combined to new data frame. When i try to run individual subscript as above, it says "Error: `path` must be a string" in console.

Comment: What exactly is stored in `fileNames` and `fileNumber`. Without knowing the exact contents of those variables, it's not really possible to say what's happening. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.